# Pythonic way to subtract one list from another with validation of presence

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

A good pythonic way to subtract one list from another is to use list comprehension:

```
# remove all elements of list2 from list1
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
```

Could I, in the same iteration, check that `list2` itself only contains elements from `list1` without separately iterating `list2`?

Comment: Only elements from `list1` are going to be present in the iteration. What are you actually asking?

Comment: You're iterating over all the elements in `list1`. Wouldn't `x` then be guaranteed to occur in `list1`? You aren't seeing any elements that are not there.

Comment: Give an example of a case where you would want to raise an error and I'll probably be able to show you how to do it.

Comment: If the order of the list doesn't matter, you can also use `set`. E.g., `list1 = set(list1).difference(set(list2))`

Comment: I realized that my question was phrased ambiguously.  Reworded to be clear.

Comment: @donnyton edited my answer, but I think the second solution (iterating twice) is more pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to explicitly iterate only once, you could remove things from list2 (or a copy of it) that are in list1. Just keep in mind that `in` and `remove` iterate through list2 anyway.

```
list_delta = []
for x in list1:
    if x not in list2:
        list_delta.append(x)
    else:
        list2.remove(x)
if list2:
    print(list2) # list2 now contains only elements not list1
else:
    pass # list2 is empty, thus contains no elements that aren't in list1
```

However, explicitly iterating twice would have pretty much the same time complexity while being way more pythonic.

```
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2]
presence = not any(x for x in list2 if x not in list1)
# presence is true if list2 only contains elements from list1
```

original misunderstood answer below

---

You don't need to check. `x` by definition has to be in `list1`, or else the iterator wouldn't provide it (since you're iterating over `list1`'s items)

But in case it might get modified while you're iterating (which is a case you should **definitely** avoid):

```py
list1 = [x for x in list1 if x not in list2 and x in list1]
```

If you need more complex behaviour like showing an error message, use an explicit loop

```
list_delta = []
for x in list1:
    if x not in list1:
        raise IndexError("oh god what")
    if x not in list2:
        list_delta.append(x)
```

But honestly this seems like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) because you should *never have to do this* to begin with.

Comment: What about concurrent modification? I'm pretty sure it's not what op is asking, but still.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking there, but if the order doesn't matter and there are no repetitions, you can use set difference as @Chih-Hsu Jack Lin mentioned in the comments:

```
list(set(list1) - set(list2))
```

And if order doesn't matter, but element count does matter, another approach is to use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
list((Counter(list1) - Counter(list2)).elements())
```